# Form not updating to db, PHP. Kind of confused why

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

I'm having a small college project about discussion room service. I'm stuck at updating the database of the rooms.
I already used `mysqli_error()` function, and that didn't return any error, I wonder why.
Here's my form code:

```
<?php
//Tahap 1. Buat koneksi Database
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$name = "pinjamruang";
$koneksi = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);

//Periksa apakah koneksi berhasil
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error: ";
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "<br   /> Error Code: ";
    echo mysqli_connect_errno();
    die();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ruangan";
$keranjang = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($keranjang);
?>

<h1 class="page-header">Edit Karyawan</h1><br>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="process/process-ruangan-edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">        
        <label for="inputKodeRuangan" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Kode Ruangan</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="kode" class="form-control" id="inputKodeRuangan" value="<?php echo $row['kode'];?>" placeholder="Kode Ruangan">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputJumlahMeja" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Jumlah Meja</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" name="meja" class="form-control" id="inputJumlahMeja" value="<?php echo $row['meja'];?>"placeholder="Jumlah Meja">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputJumlahKursi" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Jumlah Kursi</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="number" name="kursi" class="form-control" id="inputJumlahKursi" value="<?php echo $row['kursi'];?>"placeholder="Jumlah Kursi">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputStatus" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="status" class="form-control" id="inputStatus">
                    <option value="available">Tersedia</option>
                    <option value="unavailable">Tidak Tersedia</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputNote" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Catatan Khusus</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="note" class="form-control" id="inputNote" value="<?php echo $row['note'];?>"placeholder="Catatan Khusus">
        </div>
        </div>      
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's my process code:

```
<?php
// Tahap 1. Buat koneksi database
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$name = "pinjamruang";
$koneksi = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $name);

//Periksa apakah koneksi berhasil
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Error: ";
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    echo "<br   />Error Code: ";
    echo mysqli_connect_errno();
    die();
}
//Tahap 2. Lakukan Query SQL
// Dapatkan data dari form dan dibersihkan
$kode = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['kode']);
$meja = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['meja']);
$kursi = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['kursi']);
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['status']);
$note = mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi, $_POST['note']);
$sql = "UPDATE ruangan
        SET kode = '$kode',
            kursi = $kursi,
            meja = $meja,
            status = '$status',
            note = '$note'
        WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql);
echo mysqli_error($koneksi);
//header('Location: ../index.php?page=ruangan');
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm still really new at PHP and basically programming so, thanks a lot!

Comment: You should echo your `mysqli_error(..)` to know what the error is.

Comment: And you only need the one AFTER you run the `mysqli_query()`

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Also you dont check any of the `$_POST` variable actually exist before attempting to use them in the query

Comment: Alright, my bad. Thanks for the reminder, @KarloKokkak. Now that i echoed the error, it returns this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
Notice: Undefined variable: row2 in D:\Kuliah\PHP\htdocs\proj' at line 7

Comment: In your first code block - change - `$row2['id']` to - `$row['id']` . You're passing an `id` with no value.

Comment: Even though my code at line 7 doesn't have any variable called row 2..

Comment: The FIRST script does see `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" />`

Comment: Thanks everyone! Hope you guys have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form code you are referencing `$row2` which hasn't been defined yet.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row2['id']; ?>" />
```

You should change it to

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the line `WHERE id = $_POST[id]";`

Comment: Thats more like it :)

Comment: Thanks @Rubixryan! Hope you have a great day!